# an error occurred while trying to update the record. please try again. Error message when deactivate user from the community site

Tags: community, experience-cloud, user-management, guest-user

I have created the customer community plus site and set up permission to add new user and deactivate users for the external super user. External super user can create new member, no error, while deactivate (activate back existing member) the member from the site receiving error as "An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again."

Is there any special permission need to activate/deactivate user from site?

I set up the external super user with “Delegated External User Administrator” permission as explained here.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_DPUA.htm&type=5

Thanks.

Comment: The error message you've cited does not mean it's a permission issue. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful